# HTML Duplicating words

Tags: python, html, nlp

I need to know where I went wrong with this one...
So we're given this very long passage (html) that is already tagged for sentiment, word class etc and our goal is to then change the colour for all words with positive sentiment, a different colour for words with negative sentiment.
I've managed to do that but in the output, the colored words are duplicated—they are printed in color next to the original word. I just need help fixing that. Thanks!

```
if sentiment < 0.0:
        print (f"<span style='color:red;'>{word} </span", 
           file=out)
    elif sentiment > 0.0:
            print (f"<span style='color:blue;'>{word} </span", 
           file=out)
```

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be in the attached code, it's most likely right before you run this if.  ei: we need the for loop that runs through each word to see what's wrong.

Comment: this part of code can't duplicate word.